# Why is Next JS sending "Error: Connection closed. at e.exports.emit (node:events:530:35)" after button press?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Pressing one of the Next.js component buttons should run the callback function passed to them, but instead it sends an error to the output.

There are three components where I think the issue could be. This is the UserPostControls component, which creates the DeleteButton and sends it the callback it should use to delete the post. The debug message is not shown when this error occurs, so the error must be in calling the callback.

```js
import { auth } from "@/auth";
import DeleteButton from "@/app/ui/delete-button";
import { deletePost } from "@/app/lib/actions";

export default async function UserPostControls({ user, id }: { user: string, id: string }) {

    const sessionUser = await auth();

    if (sessionUser?.user?.name == user) {
        return (
            <span>
                <DeleteButton callback={async () => {
                    "use server";
                    console.debug("Deleting post");
                    deletePost(id);
                }} />
            </span>
        )
    }

    return <span></span>;
}
```

This is the DeleteButton component, where the actual button is. The callback is passed in as an argument, and the intent is that the callback is called when the button is pressed.

```
import deleteIcon from "@/app/static/icons8-delete.svg"
import Image from "next/image";

export default function DeleteButton({ callback }: { callback: () => Promise<undefined> }) {
    return <button className="flex flex-row m-1 text-black hover:text-red-700 float-right" onClick={callback}>
        Delete Ad
        <Image 
            className="inline" 
            src={deleteIcon} 
            width={20} 
            height={20} 
            alt="Delete" 
        />
    </button>;

}
```

This is the output on the server side.

```
⨯ Error: Connection closed.
    at e.exports.emit (node:events:530:35)
```

This is the output on the client side.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Connection closed.
react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:1792:14
```

At first I thought it was an issue with the button being a client-side component, so I moved it to server side rendering but it didn't change anything.

Using a client-side function as a callback to call a server-side asynchronous function makes the linter mad, so I can't do that, and I don't know what else to try.

None of the debug messages in the deletePost() method are run either, so I'd like to know if anyone else has had this issue or knows if I've made a silly mistake since it's my first real project with Next.js components and server-side rendering.